# Eloquent ORM select all with limit and column name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi how can I select limited number of all the item from model and the selection with certain names.

eg:

```
$product = Product::all()->limit(4)->select('id','name');
```

Most of example start with `Product::find(1)` but my case, I don't have id. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the other methods first, then call `get` at the end:

```php
$products = Product::limit(4)->select('id', 'name')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Limit Query Results

To limit the number of results returned from the query, or to skip a given number of results in the query, you may use the `skip()` and `take()` methods:

Example of `User` model which extends Eloquent:

```
$users = User::take(5)->skip(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Product::all() will be used when get all data without any condition. You need to use get method.

you need to

```
$products = Product::select('id', 'name')->limit(4)->get();
```